# Query String for Hiding Trashed Items in Drive API V3

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to use two query parameters in one call that'll give me the files in a folder and also filters out the files that were trashed from that folder.

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='${folder_id}'+in+parents&q=trashed%3Dfalse`

The problem is it only executes the first query, where it gives me everything inside the folder with the `folder_id`, including files that were trashed and I don't want that. I'm trying to get the files inside that folder that are **NOT** in the trash.

When I take out the portion with the `folder_id` and do just the following, it works:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse`

I'm trying to do both in one call to the url. Can someone please give me an idea what should be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After navigating further through the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters), I found that this line answers the question:

> Combine clauses with the conjunctions and or or, and negate the query with not

So the correct way to concat two queries would be this:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='${folder_id}'+in+parents+and+trashed%3Dfalse`